# Dropdown swatch has to display the concerned text

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.2.3, configurable-swatches

[image]

This image has the dropdown swatch with the color like blue, red ,etc inside it.

If its a text swatch then it displays as 16mp or 48mp based on the values clicked but here in drop down swatch I couldn't make it possible to display the color on place where i have the text "topp".

I have made few changes in configurable.js , configurable.php, wrapper.phtml and renderer.phtml but I couldn't get the desired output.

**Note :**

The color either as blue, red which is clicked on the drop down swatch has to be reflected in the place where I wrote the text as "topp".

Comment: Is topp is config product name?

Comment: No its just the text which i added in renderer.phtml to check the location where it reflects. @NareshRupareliya

Comment: When you click on 16MP or 48MP then display that value place of topp?

Comment: when I click on 16MP or 48MP , magento automatically displays the value by default, but when its a drop down it doesn't show up. @NareshRupareliya

Comment: can u please provide me site reference? so i can check there. because i don't understand why u added topp text in renderer.phtml. what is your exact requirement

Comment: ya sure. https://puffy.com/products/puffy-lux-mattress

Comment: In the above site , you can select the size as queen, king ,etc and the values of the bed  size changes dynamically based on the size clicked, thats the exact thing i'm trying to bring it on my site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102148/discussion-between-haerriz-and-naresh-rupareliya).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to override `swatch-renderer.js` file in your theme

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js

Download file from this link : [Swatch Renderer](https://github.com/nareshrupareliya/Swatch-Renderer)

**Note :** run upgrade command and flush cache and check

Hope this will help you!